# Hide Vimeo logo on showcase (via API)

Tags: vimeo-api, vimeo-player

Is there a way to set the setting `hide_vimeo_logo` (on the Vimeo-Player) programmatically (via the Vimeo API) for a Vimeo showcase?

It's not listed in the parameters that can be changed on a showcase. I tried anyway with `embed.hide_vimeo_logo` and did not get an error, but it didn't change the setting either.

Another approach could be applying an embed preset to a showcase, but I couldn't find a way to do it. Are embed presets only for videos?